# How to make external display go to sleep after xx mins?

Tags: display, macos, sleep-wake

I'm using my new 2016 12" Macbook as a "desktop" by connecting it to an external display, USB Keyboard/mouse and running it in "clamshell mode". Works beautifully except the display never goes to sleep. I was kinda figuring it would go to sleep just the same way the internal display does but it will stay on for hours if I let it. I did set up a hot-corner to sleep the display and that works fine but that means I always need to do it manually. How can I get this to work so that it acts normally? Do energy saver settings not apply to external displays?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step I would reset both your NVRAM and SMC, as well as double check your Energy Saver settings.

**Resetting the NVRAM on an early-2016 12" MacBook model**

Follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Resetting the SMC on an early-2016 12" MacBook model**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**Energy Saver Settings**

You don't specify in your question how you've configured your Energy Saver settings, but you may want to double-check what you've actually set under the Power Adapter tab. I've come across many instances where MacBook users forget that there's two tabs you can configure.

Comment: I tred the SMC and PRAM resets and it didn't seem to make any difference. I don't think it's a technical issue preventing the display from sleeping, as I can make it sleep manually using a hot-corner, but rather the energy settings aren't applying to external displays. This may be by design, but I'm not sure which is why I posted here. My Energy Saver settings are defaults, and work as expected when being used as a laptop.

Comment: The Energy Saver settings should apply to external displays unless the built-in settings of the display override these in some way. What model display do you have? The reason I mention checking Energy Saver settings is that presumably you have your MacBook connected to AC power when you're using your display, so I wanted to make sure that the settings under the Power Adapter tab are in fact what you think they are? I know that seems a bit obvious, but I've come across many users who just didn't realise this. Also, when you refer to Hot Corners, do you mean you're activating your Screen Saver?